# API de validação CEP e CPF em Java

Tags: java, api

Alguém conhece uma API em Java que valide CPF e CEP?

Answer (score 1):

A Caelum tem uma API pra isso que é mantida também pela comunidade.

[Site Official](http://stella.caelum.com.br/)

[Stela GitHub](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/wiki)

Comment: http://www.republicavirtual.com.br/busca_de_cep/Java/#java

Answer (score 0):

Alguns links e apis importantes para CEP:

http://correiosapi.apphb.com/
[Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400/como-buscar-um-endere%C3%A7o-por-cep-nos-correios)